# Get return type of current function in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming

This question is similar to [Get return type of function in macro (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666735/get-return-type-of-function-in-macro-c) but it is 10 Years old and is not answered. Any other solution would be accepted.

I want to create an assert macro that only returns from the function if the condition isn't met, Like:

```
#define ASSERT(X) if(!(X)) return {};
```

This doesn't work if the containing function returns void, but I don't want to create 2 macros. I want to be able to add/remove return values without changing the code. My idea is to create a helper function:

```
template<class T>
T re(){
    if constexpr( std::is_same<T, void>::value ){
        return;
    }
    else if constexpr( ! std::is_same<T, void>::value ){
        return {};
    }
}
```

Now the macro could work like:

```
double f(int *i){
    if(i == nullptr){
        typedef std::invoke_result<decltype(&f),int>::type T; // only works for this function
        return re<T>();
    }
    return 1.0;
}
```

But I require the return type T of the current function without having to call something like `ASSERT(i != nullptr, double)` because then I could simply use 2 macros. Also, macros like __func__ and std::source_location are only strings.

Comment: `return {}` doesn't work, but `return void()` does work.

Comment: When I did something like this, I just ended up writing 3 separate macros that all called a common macro. The only values I *ever* had to return were `-1`, `nullptr`, and `false`. Edit: actually, I just peeked at the code, and there is no `void` case - how is such a function supposed to indicate the error anyway?

Comment: @o11c for example I have my own allocator where I don't care whether someone calls free(nullptr), but yes this question is more about the limits of c++ than a real problem I have.

Comment: Hiding operations like `return` in a `ASSERT` macro could be surprising, and make the code less obvious.If there's a lot of points where you need this macro I would consider instead to split in smaller functions, as recommended by uncle Bob

Comment: Is it an option to use throw instead of return? Then you also would not have any issue with the returned value.

Comment: @MatG yes this macro should be called more like IGNORE_THAT_THE_FUCTION_WAS_CALLED_IF_THE_CONDITION_IS_NOT_MET but I think that name is too long and I have not found a better name yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (GCC, Clang) /`__FUNCSIG__` (MSVC), a non-standard extension that gives you the name of the current function, including the return type.

You can analyze the string at compile-time to see if it has `void` in it or not:

```
#include <string_view>

struct AnyType
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T()
    {
        return {};
    }
};

template <bool IsVoid>
auto foo()
{
    if constexpr (IsVoid)
        return;
    else
        return AnyType{};
}

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define FUNCNAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#else
#define FUNCNAME __FUNCSIG__
#endif

#define ASSERT(x) if (!bool(x)) return foo<std::string_view(FUNCNAME).starts_with("void ")>()

void x()
{
    ASSERT(0);
}

int y()
{
    ASSERT(0);
}
```

This needs more testing to make sure you can't break it with trailing return types, and by adding various stuff to function definition (attributes, calling conventions, etc).

Comment: Nice one :-) Here's a [minor tweak](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8d481sPf4) that uses [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) instead. The string returned by `function_name()` also has an implementation-defined format, but one can skip the macro tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unaware of the return type of the function, there is no expression `X` where the statement `return X;` will be valid for both a `void`-returning function and a function that returns an arbitrary type.

One can create a special user-defined template type where `return X;` will be valid for a variety of types. For example `return std::nullopt;` is always valid for a function returning any `optional<T>`. You can create a similar type with similar implicit conversion properties from an object like `nullopt`, one with a specialization to allow a `void` type to be "carried" (`std::optional<void>` is not allowed, though you could use a stateless type as an equivalent to `void`).

Of course, this now requires the caller to extract the returned value (if any) from your type. This also means that it has to check to see if a value was returned or not.

The `expected<T, E>` type (of which there are several implementations) represents a type like what you're talking about. The difference is that they carry either a `T` or `E` (with a special case for `T` == `void`), where carrying an `E` represents an error value that the consumer of the return is expected to handle.

But all these require changing the function's actual return value. If you're dead-set on using simple types like `void`, `double`, `int`, etc, then you're going to have to have different macros for whatever return you're doing.

Comment: _a stateless type as an equivalent to `void`_, aka a unit type, e.g. [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate).

Comment: `return f<T>();` is valid if both f and the current function return the same type, even if that is `void`. AFAIU the OP's issue is more the lack of `decltype(return)` or other introspection feature.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Yes, if you could get the return type of the current function, then you could do that. But since you can't, my point still stands.